# How to check old password and update it to new password?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Nothing happened in my code. No error showing, but the password is not changing. After I clicked the submit button it only redirect to the password_view.

Here is my password view: password_view.php

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('password');?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2"> Old Password:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input class="form-control" name="oldPassword" placeholder="Old Password" type="password">
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('oldPassword'); ?></span>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2"> New Password:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input class="form-control" name="newPassword" placeholder="New Password" type="password">
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('newPassword'); ?></span>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2"> Re-type Password:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input class="form-control" name="renewPassword" placeholder="Re-type Password" type="password">
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('renewPassword'); ?></span>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2"></label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-grad btn-rect">Submit</button>
                <a href ="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/main" class="btn btn-default btn-grad btn-rect">Cancel</a>
            </div>
    </div>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Here is my password controller: password.php

```
public function index()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('oldPassword','Old Password','trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[30]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('newPassword','New Password','trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[30]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('renewPassword','Retype Password','trim|required|matches[newPassword]');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('password_view');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->model('account_model');
        $this->load->view('password_view');
        $query = $this->account_model->checkOldPassword($this->input->post('oldPassword'));

        if($query)
        {
            $query = $this->account_model->saveNewPassword($this->input->post('newPassword'));

            if($query)
            {
                $this->session->sess_destroy();
                $data['error']='Password Change Successfully. Please login to Continue.';
                $this->load->view('password_view',$data);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Oops! Error.  Please try again later!!!</div>');
                redirect('account/editPassword');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my password model: account_model.php

```
public function checkOldPassword($oldPassword)
{
    $this->db->select('AID');
    $this->db->where('AID',$this->session->userdata('id'));
    $this->db->where('Password',$this->input->post('oldPassword'));
    $query=$this->db->get('tblaccount');
    if($query->num_rows>0)
    {
        $row=$query->row();

        if($oldPassword == $row->Password)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public function saveNewPassword($newPassword)
{
    $data = array(
            'Password' => $newPassword
            );

    $this->db->where('AID', $this->session->userdata('id'));
    $this->db->where('Password',$this->input->post('oldPassword'));
    $query = $this->db->update('tblaccount', $data);

    if($query)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Changes in Old password rule**

add **callback_checkOldPassword** rule in **oldPassword** field

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('oldPassword','Old Password','trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[30]|callback_checkOldPassword');
```

**Changes in checkOldPassword method**

set error message for **checkOldPassword** rule

```
public function checkOldPassword($oldPassword)
{
    $this->db->select('AID');
    $this->db->where('AID',$this->session->userdata('id'));
    $this->db->where('Password',$this->input->post('oldPassword'));
    $query=$this->db->get('tblaccount');
    if($query->num_rows>0)
    {
        return true;
    }else{
        $this->form_validation->set_message('checkOldPassword', 'wrong old password.');
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Same, nothing happened.

Comment: Please try edited answer i have changes in checkOldPassword method

Comment: Not working. Even I try to input wrong password in the old password, it does not show anything.

Comment: It's working now. But the problem is it shows no error message when the password I input in the old password text field is wrong or not the same in database.

Comment: Please try to trash your code and confirm your script same as above answer. Above solution is work for me if any solution found then please tell me

Comment: It's working now. I manage to put an error if the current password is wrong. Thanks for your help!